# Исключить фразу из результата при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

На вход приходит строка с наименованием системы и типом запроса. Пример:

```
Проблема в системе Наименование.
```

Такие типы запроса обрабатываются регуляркой через regex `(Наименование|System)`
Но нужно, чтобы не обрабатывались запросы на доступ в данную систему. Пример:

```
Предоставить доступ в Наименование.
```

Пытался использовать `^.*(Наименование|System)(?!.*(доступ Наименование|System))`, но данная регулярка постоянно находит первую часть, что неверно.

Помогите написать корректное регулярное, пожалуйста.

Comment: негативный просмотр назад вам нужен

Comment: Не очень понятно какой результат должен быть у регулярки. Т.е. вот две строки поступают на обработку - что после работы регулянного выражения должно получиться?
И вообще не очень понятно зачем тут регулярка. Если нужно отдельно куда-то фильтровать строки с проблемами - так и фильтруйте их по первой части. Т.е. по наличию подстроки "Проблема в системе"

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
^(?!.*доступ\s+в\s+(?:Наименование|System)).*(?:Наименование|System)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/0FVf33/2).

Подробности

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!.*доступ[а-яё]*\s+в\s+(?:Наименование|System)) - после ноля и более символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, не должно быть слов` доступ в Наименование`или`доступ в System`
- `.*` - ноль и более символов (отличных от символов перевода строки)
- `(?:Наименование|System)` - одно из двух строковых значений.